# directing gstreamer NV12 video to v4l2loopback sink

Tags: v4l2, gstreamer-1.0, v4l2loopback

I want to direct a video with the NV12 pixel format to a v4l2loopback device but I failed in all my attempts to do so. I tried this pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=NV12 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

and `/dev/video1` is my loopback device. Also I tried to use the `v4l2loopback-ctl` script to set the loopback device capapilities to NV12 without cuccess

```
./v4l2loopback-ctl set-caps "video/x-raw, format=NV12" /dev/video1
```

This pipeline works for other video formats , so, is it valid to direct NV12 to v4l2loopback devices?

I am working on ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.13.0-37-generic and v4l2loopback version 0.11.0 compiled from source with this [commit](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/commit/05a03e2b624be632bce4f2260a7211f396bbdff3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening an [issue](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/169) on the project GitHub repository the answer was that this feature is not supported. I added it and my changes is merged in [this commit](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/commit/466c166afedc7bcc69737c87982fb5f1326f7402).